# Drag On ListView When ItemsTemplate is defined

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp, drag-and-drop

I am developing a UWP application and in one scenario I have to add Drag and drop feature on a ListView . But DragItemsStarting event doesn't get trigger when ItemsTemplate is defined.

In one scenario when I do Drag operation on ListViewItem by selecting its border it works well but when I do the drag on item it doesn't work.

[Here is the Image for drag operation on items border:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdJ7q.jpg)

Here is the XAML code:

```
 <ListView Grid.Row="3"
              ScrollViewer.IsScrollInertiaEnabled="True"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"
              CanDragItems="True"
              CanReorderItems="True"
              ReorderMode="Enabled"
              AllowDrop="True"
              SelectionMode="Single"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              DragItemsStarting="{x:Bind VM.DragItemsStarting, Mode=OneWay}"
              DragOver="{x:Bind VM.DragOver, Mode=OneWay}"
              Drop="{x:Bind VM.DragDrop, Mode=OneWay}"
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind ItemSource, Mode=OneWay}">

   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Model">
                <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                        Command="{Binding DataContext.PageCommand, ElementName=pageMain}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ShowName,Mode=OneWay}"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   Foreground="Black"
                                   TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"
                                   Margin="3" />
                        <ProgressBar Grid.Row="1"
                                     Margin="0"
                                     Value="25"
                                     Height="8"
                                     VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                     Foreground="Green" />
                    </Grid>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Is there any way I can perform drag operation on complete ListViewItem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid the use of `Button` directly inside `ItemTemplate` if you are having drag and drop features in your application, use a `Grid` or something else.

Now to enable click feature on `ListItem` set `IsItemClickEnabled` property to `True` and use `ItemClick` event on the `ListView`.

Comment: Thanks Ipsit Gaur. Issues is resolved now. Culprit was button inside the template.